# How to convert x-www-form-urlencoded to object

Tags: javascript, json, node-modules, x-www-form-urlencoded

**I'm using an API sending data in x-www-form-urlencoded type, like this**

```
{
    "--------------------------b293caf16a07c90a\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name": "\"api_key\"\r\n\r\2d5d4f4f4d5d6f4d5f4d4f5\r\n--------------------------b293caf16a07c90a\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name=\"invoice_key\"\r\n\r\nYAtFRHOTxeONJYP\r\n--------------------------b293caf16a07c90a\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name=\"invoice_id\"\r\n\r\n1020984\r\n--------------------------b293caf16a07c90a\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name=\"payment_method\"\r\n\r\nFawry\r\n--------------------------b293caf16a07c90a\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name=\"invoice_status\"\r\n\r\npending\r\n--------------------------b293caf16a07c90a\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name=\"referenceNumber\"\r\n\r\n991008287\r\n--------------------------b293caf16a07c90a\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; name=\"pay_load\"\r\n\r\nFTest\r\n--------------------------b293caf16a07c90a--\r\n"
}
```

**Is there a way (like npm package) to convert this data to Javascript object or JSON to use it in my website?**

Answer (score 0):

You could try parsing it like this:

```
try{JSON.parse(data)}
```

Comment: It returns error Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
then I used ``` JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) ``` but it returns object with the same data !!

Comment: What exactly are your input and desired output?